# linked list method vs functions

Tags: python, oop, linked-list

I am trying to understand why a function would work as an external function, but won't work if I move it into the class as a method.

Quickly I created a Linked list class:

```
class Link:
    """A linked list."""
    empty = ()

    def __init__(self, first, rest=empty):
        assert rest is Link.empty or isinstance(rest, Link)
        self.first = first
        self.rest = rest

    def __str__(self):
        string = '<'
        while self.rest is not Link.empty:
            string += str(self.first) + ', '
            self = self.rest
        return string + str(self.first) + '>'
```

so when I try to create a function called stretch, so that I can:

```
def stretch(s, repeat=0):
    """Replicate the kth element k times, for all k in s."""
    if s is not Link.empty:
        stretch(s.rest, repeat+1)
        for i in range(repeat):
            s.rest = Link(s.first, s.rest)
```

It worked:

```
a = Link(3, Link(4, Link(5, Link(6))))
print(a)  # >>> <3, 4, 5, 6>
stretch(a)
print(a)  # >>> <3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6>
```

However, when I try to create this function as a class method:

```
def stretch(self, repeat=0):
    """Replicate the kth element k times, for all k in a linked list."""
    if self is not Link.empty:
        self.rest.stretch(repeat+1)
        for i in range(repeat):
            self.rest = Link(self.first, self.rest)
```

Now it won't work:

```
b = Link(3, Link(4, Link(5, Link(6))))
b.stretch()
print(b)
# >>> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'stretch'
```

I understand that when `b` get to the last element, `b.rest` will be an empty tuple, but in the method, it says `if self is not Link.empty` it should not execute anything. Why is it giving me error message?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you define the second `stretch` _in_ the class?

Comment: @DYZ Of course I did.

Comment: Ask yourself: when is `self`, which is an instance of `Link`, *ever* `Link.empty`, which is *not* an instance of `Link`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happens on the line `self.rest.stretch(repeat+1)`. Since you do not pass the second parameter to the constructor in `Link(3, Link(4, Link(5, Link(6))))`, the default value of `()` is used to initialize the field `self.rest`, and the value of this field never changes thereafter. Thus, `self.rest.stretch(repeat+1)` is actually `().stretch(repeat+1)`. Naturally, `()`, an empty tuple, does not have the attribute `stretch`.

The first function works because it does not have the offending statement.

Comment: I understand why it gets down to `().stretch(n)`. But in the method, isn't there a `if` condition to help preventing an empty tuple to be executed on the later part of self.rest.stretch?

Comment: So how should I write this function into the class then?

Comment: It is not about `self`, it is about `self.rest`. You never check if `self. rest` is empty. As a side note, you should have used `None` instead of an empty tuple.

Answer (score 1):

The first function works whether `s` passed to `stretch` is either a `Link` object or `Link.empty`.

The second member function doesn't work when the object is `Link.empty`, because `Link.empty` is a tuple that doesn't have the method. You never even make it into the function where your `if` would catch it.

You need to move the `if` outside, before the call.

Comment: I see. That makes sense, because the `stretch` is in the `Class Link` now, so a tuple won't find this method, no matter what `if` condition I gave. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 I just added a little more explanation.